# Read command in bash script not executing as a read command and outputting text straight to command line

Tags: bash, shell-script, read

I have a bash script that I wrote to automate some commands, and one of the first lines in the script isn't working on the computer that it needs to run on. The code is below

```
#!/bin/bash 
#some comments
read -p 'press enter to begin'
echo "Please Wait..."
#rest of the script
```

It is a fairly simple start to the automation script and it works fine on the virtual machine I used to test and run the script, but when the script runs in the working environment it outputs the text
`read -p 'press enter to begin'` straight to the command line and then stops running; instead of the desired result of a read command with the prompt `press enter to begin`, waiting for the user's input, and then echoing `Please wait...` while the script runs.

```
sudo bash ./path/to/file.sh
```

I am not sure what to do to fix this problem as I can't find anything else about this online.

I've gone through all the basic troubleshooting steps; made sure the file is executable, run while specifying that it is a bash file (it actually wouldn't run without the bash callout), and running the same read command that is in the script directly on the command line (which outputs the desired result of `press enter to begin` and waiting for a user input).
Any suggestions? I plan on running the script using the `set -x` command when  have a chance today or tomorrow.

Comment: Of course it'll wait after printing `press enter to begin`; you're reading a line of text from the user with that as the prompt. Or are you saying that it prints literally `read -p 'press enter to begin'` when it's run? If so, please [edit] your question to explain exactly how you're running the script.

Comment: indeed, you've asked it to read something into the REPLY variable; did you hit ENTER at the prompt? Do you *want* the user to "press enter to begin"?

Comment: @roaima I clarified the problem statement. The script literally outputs `read -p 'press enter to begin'` when its run.

Comment: OK. So how (exactly) does this script get run?

Comment: @roaima `sudo bash ./path/to/file.sh` It is supposed to print the prompt to the command line and after the user presses enter the script will run through as normal. It should work, it does work on the virtual machine I use, but for some reason, on the computer that it actually needs to be run on, the line in my script is printed directly to the command window instead of being run as a read command. Not sure what else to say about how it gets run because it literally can't run if the read commands aren't working

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the script you've shown us. Do the five lines - exactly as you've shown above - trigger this same problem on your production server? If not, please provide a minimal example that does trigger the issue.

Comment: Which distro, what version of bash (and do they differ between environments)?

Comment: Voting to close as unreproducible, because the OP hasn't confirmed the script in the question is exactly what's triggering the problem. We can't make accurate assessments on approximations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why the script was breaking, when using the read command I had

`read -p 'prompt'`

Instead of

`read -p "prompt"`

When I changed it to the double quotes the script ran fine for the beginning part that I was asking about in this question. 
Why did this specific format break the script? Idk, the machine I'm running it on is very picky and has some weird formatting preferences about things that should work, and do work in other environments.

Comment: This should not have changed anything. Using `"prompt"` or `'prompt'` is exactly equivalent if the string `prompt` is static.  Do you have a quote somewhere earlier in the program that is not closed?

Comment: This is literally the beginning of the program and it ran fine on the virtual machine, I have no clue why it did this

Comment: You had `#some comments` as the second line?

Comment: yeah I had a few lines of comments that are irrelevant to the issue I was having

Comment: I don't think they were irrelevant. There is nothing wrong with what you've shown here. Therefore there must have been something strange with the part(s) you've omitted.

Comment: Its nice that you think that, but they were definitely irrelevant because I fixed the issue without changing anything except the quotation type. Tbh the root cause of this whole thing was most likely the newline character (\r) that appeared due to transferring the document from a windows machine to linux. This was the cause of every other problem I was having so I wouldn't be surprised if it was why this read command format was not working.